# FB Request Dialog - Image not showing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, plugins

I'm trying to load the image on the FB request dialog, it is not showing if i use the image property. Is there any other way? I can't load the image marked in red.

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to upload both two logos of your app on app setting dashboard.

[image]

Comment: That is the right answer. I read a documentation somewhere that i can set a custom image to what can be shown as an image, my bad. Thanks for helping out.